# Why is my installer installing to c:\ rather than than c:\Program Files(x86)\ as it should do

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, .net-3.5

Part of my job is creating MSI installers for my company's .NET Windows Forms application.  It's been installed on literally hundreds of computers at dozens of clients, on Windows XP (not for a long time!), Windows 7, and these days, on Windows 10.

It's a 32 bit application, so it installs by default into

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\My Company Name\MyAppName
```

It has worked like this for years - since 2005 in fact, and since then through dozens of updates.

Today at one of my clients, despite the above folder being shown as the default install folder while running the MSI, the application ended up being installed into the root of the `c:` drive.

On another computer within the same organisation, running the same installer ended up with the application installed to the root of the `d:` drive.

It's almost as if there's a symbolic link set up, but the IT manager at said organisation says they don't use them.

I've now tried the same installer on a desktop, a laptop (both running Windows 10 Enterprise 1903) and a VM, running Windows 10 Enterprise 1809, and the installation ends up exactly where it should, and has for more than a decade.

I've never seen this before, can someone suggest a possible cause?

Comment: Did you check the environment variables? There’s a dynamic variable called `ProgramFiles` that returns either `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: have you created a verbose MSI log of the install? Could you share a log from a working and non working computer?